# MSN Messenger Password Recovery on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-live-messenger, password-recovery

I inherited an old laptop when my father died.  It has MSN Messenger 7.5 on it and a password in the text field (and in the system registry).  I'd like to recover this password, if possible, but am not sure if it's possible/safe.  There apparently are recovery tools, but I'm not sure what to trust.  I'd prefer an open source tool, but I see there's a Nirsoft freeware tool.  I have no experience with Nirsoft or any other developer in a matter such as this, so I don't know who to trust or what tools to use.

I'd rather not break the laptop's OS since I do have some use for it.  I also don't have any recovery CDs for it.

Comment: I have used other Nirsoft programs and I haven't had any problem with them. But if you are afraid it could do something bad, you can try running it in a [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com) sandbox.

Comment: nirsoft is ok, it's safe http://nirsoft.net/utils/mspass.html

Comment: Why don't you just reset the Microsoft Account's password?

Comment: I don't know if I can reset the password.  I don't know if the account is even valid.  I'm more interested in the actual password since my father likely reused the same one on various other accounts.  (I already found a file that lists descriptions of passwords for retail web sites, but nothing about MSN Messenger.)

Comment: An update, I tried the NirSoft program and got the password.  Turns out it was one I already knew and probably could have guessed if I'd bothered trying.  I felt I had to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I suggest you take a snapshot of your system using [Redo Backup](http://redobackup.org/), an open source easy to use backup tool. If anything goes wrong you can just restore the image and recover from any harm that may occur later.

After you take a backup you can give to [Asteriks Key](http://www.lostpassword.com/asterisk.htm), or [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/astlog.html) or to [its alternatives](http://www.callingallgeeks.org/5-software-to-reveal-your-asterisk-hidden-password/) like [Show Password](http://www.scalabium.com/showpw.htm) a try. However as far as I can see there is not any open source software for this purpose. Please make sure that your security (antivirus, firewall) software is running while trying these applications.